# How to use npm module with Brunch

Tags: node.js, browserify, brunch

I'm using Brunch.io and I'm trying to use an npm module (https://github.com/dylang/shortid in this case) in client side. `shortid` says it's compatible with browserify, so I tried many things including

- Browserify the module with the following command:

  ```
  browserify -r ./index.js:shortid > /project/vendor/shortid.js
  ```
- and use it in the application code:

  ```
  var shortid = require("shortid");
  ```

Web page is giving the following error:

```
 TypeError: require.register is not a function
 TypeError: loaderPath.indexOf is not a function
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Yes, I used npm to install both browserify and shortid. No, only shortid is in the dependencies section of package.json of the project, because browserify is installed globally.

Comment: Did you try [browserify-brunch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-brunch)?